Adding websockets support to Keycloak via quarkus extension or other
Keyclock version: 26.0.2
As part of my keycloak-graphql project, I want to add Websockets support. For this, I was thinking of using the quarkus-websockets extension. The question is: how do I integrate the quarkus-websockets extension into Keycloak? I initially tried incorporating it (and its transitive dependencies) into my Keycloak extension "fat" JAR using the Maven shade plugin. Not surprisingly there were many overlapping files and the Keycloak server failed to start when I copied that JAR to the providers directory. Note that if I just copy the quarkus-websockets-deployment JAR file alone to the providers directory, the Keycloak server also fails to start. I've seen some posts where they copied the Quarkus extension JAR and it's transitive dependencies into the providers directory. However, the quarkus-websockets extension has many dependencies so this doesn't seem practical.
So what's the best way to go about this? Since my ultimate goal is to integrate Websockets into the Keycloak server, I'd also be willing to use a Websockets implementation other than quarkus-websockets if anyone has any suggestions.
Building Keycloak from scratch to include the extension is not really an option since I want folks to be able to install my graphql extension into an existing Keycloak server.
